# Design a bilateral price negotiation for assets swap

Tags: probability

Person alpha owns asset A.
Person beta owns asset B.
Alpha and beta wish to swap their assets A and B and settle the net cash of agreed price of A and B.
What's the best mechanism to agree on price A and price B?
Assume there is no third-party pricing A and B. The price is reached iteratively in a "bi-lateral negotiation". Target the least possible number of counterbids.

I have identified two options, but happy to hear alternative ideas.

Option 1:
First round:
Alpha lodge a price offer for B.
Beta lodge a price offer for A.
Two prices can be lodged at different times.

Second round:
Alpha counter Beta's offer for A.
Beta counter Alpha's offer for B.
Two counter must be lodged at the same time.

Alpha and Beta sit down and discuss their net delta and achieve a middle way.

Option B:
Alpha lodge a price offer for B and an Ask price for A.
Beta lodge a price offer for A and Ask price for B.
Offers must be lodge at same time with no delay.

Option c?